# Best practise for views for resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

So I've been developing my first webapp in Rails and have mostly been focusing on the backend functionality (models). I started building my app with scaffolds for all my tables and modified the views so that I could test if my methods, relationships and models were working as I intended.

Now that the backend is close to completed, I have started to work on the front end. I purchased the Inspinia theme on wrapbootstrap and don't want to go the scaffold route again since I feel like there is a lot of stuff that I would be repeating between tables. Things like forms, lists, menu's etc.

I need views for things like orders, shipments, SKUs, etc. Between these resources the lists and forms will be mostly the same, but obviously the records and attributes will be different as well as some of the actions. Additionally some lists like shipments will be repeated, one list view for all shipments and a list view that shows the shipments for a specific order.

I currently have 11 tables in my app that I need views for. If I follow the scaffold route I will end up with 55 html files. A scaffold creates for each resource:

- _form
- edit
- index
- new
- show

What way should I structure my views in a best practice fashion?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is generally as follows:

Say you have an object named `resource`:

```
- app
  - views
     - resources  # note plural here
       - _form.html.erb
       - new.html.erb
       - show.html.erb
       - index.html.erb
       - edit.html.erb
```

So if you had a `users` table with a `User` model:

```
- app
  - views
     - users
       - _form.html.erb
       - new.html.erb
       - show.html.erb
       - index.html.erb
       - edit.html.erb
```

if you're rendering a collection partial (e.g. if you're calling render <%= render @users %> in your index.html), then you might want to add a `_user.html.erb` partial as well:

```
- app
  - views
     - users
       - *_user.html.erb*
       - _form.html.erb
       - new.html.erb
       - show.html.erb
       - index.html.erb
       - edit.html.erb
```

Each user object in @users will be passed to the `_user.html.erb` partial as a local variable with the name `user`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So this is pretty much the same as the scaffold structure. I guess I'll just have to create partials in a smart way so that I can reuse for example _form.html.erb and _list.html.erb between all my resources.